# File size when using Webpack, Node, Express, React, React-Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-2

Webpack is bundling a file to the size of 1.34mb for a simple server. To me, it seems unnecessarily large considering how limited the server is. I know that using express, react, react-router, etc. will balloon the file, but to me, it seems huge!

Firstly, I was wondering if I was using webpack correctly? Secondly, where should I start to look to make it smaller?

server.js

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')

import React from 'react'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import routes from './src/routes/routes'

var app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use(function(rq, rs, nx){
    console.log("rq.url: ", rq.url)
    nx()
})

app.get('*', function(req, res){

    match({
        routes: routes,
        location: req.url
    }, (err, redirect, props) => {

        if(err){
            res.status(500).send(err.message)   
        } else if(redirect) {
            res.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
        } else if (props) {
            console.log("PROPS: ", props)

            let appHtml = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props} />)

            res.status(200).send(renderPage(appHtml))       
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not Found')
        }                        
    })
})

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8089

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('listening on port ' + PORT)
})

function renderPage(appHtml){
    return `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>React With Server</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="main">${appHtml}</div>
                <script src="/javascript/bundle.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    `
}
```

webapack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.js'),
        output: {
            filename: 'server.bundle.js',
            path: __dirname
        },
        target: 'node',
        node: {
            __filename: true,
            __dirname: true
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    options: {
                        presets: ['latest', 'react']
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could uglify the code while bundeling, should shave ~50% off file size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [Production build](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/).

```
webpack -p
```

The `-p` flag automatically enables production mode, which optimises the bundle. Or you can configure those steps [manually](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#the-manual-way-configuring-webpack-for-multiple-environments). With this the bundle's size is only 1/3 of the original.

From here you can start looking what actually makes your bundle the size it is, for example by using [Webpack Bundle Analyzer](https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer).

[image: server.bundle.js content]

As you can see `db.json` from [mime-db](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db) is by far the biggest part of the bundle, taking up about a fourth of the total size. And `react-dom` in total also takes up about the same space.

You might be wondering why you have `mime-db` in the bundle. If you are using [Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn), you can run the [why](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/why) command:

```
yarn why mime-db
```

Which tells you:

```
This module exists because "express#accepts#mime-types" depends on it.
```

So you can't really get rid of that. While using Express and React you probably won't get much lower in size of the bundle.